# Manage pages in database in Django 1.5

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

Is it possible to organize your urls.py with a Django model? I would like to create a admin interface to manage pages, and output the pages as links in the navigation, but I will run into problems with parameters. The pages should take different parameters. Am I on the wrong track? Is it possible to find a project which has already done it on Github or other open source code repository sites?

Answer (score 0):

Django comes with a [`flatpages`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/flatpages/) app that does what you need.

Answer (score 0):

I guess [Django CMS](https://www.django-cms.org/en/) does that. It holds the whole site structure in DB.

Comment: or [feincms](http://www.feincms.org/) or any other `cms`, most of which depend on [django-mptt](http://django-mptt.github.io/django-mptt/) in someway